CefSharp WPF Upgrade Needs Another Reference?
I have a CefSharp project using WPF and I'm upgrading my reference from 105.3.390 to 119.4.30 (those are specific versions I need based on the program that is hosting my code).  Why I upgrade I get a few errors that I can't seem to figure out.  The first is on this code line:
browser.LoadError += (sender, e) =>
            ShowBrowserError(
                new Exception($"<br />Frame:\t{e.Frame}<br />URL:\t{e.FailedUrl}<br />Error Code:\t{e.ErrorCode}"));

It tells me The type 'LoadErrorEventArgs' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'CefSharp, Version=119.4.30.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138'
I'm confused by this.  Generally with an error like this you just install the package it's referencing.  However, when I go to NuGet I don't see a package with just the name CefSharp.  I see CefSharp.Common but that should already be referenced as a sub-package of CefSharp.Wpf.  I did try to reference it directly in case it wanted that but no change there.  I'm not sure where to get the package that it wants.
I also have the code lines _browser.LoadHtml(Utility.GetErrorHtml(ex)); and Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());.  It's telling me LoadHtml and Cef are not defined at all, not even that it's defined in an assembly that's not referenced.  From what I can see in the documentation this should still be valid so what am I missing here?

Ok I figured this one out.  Here is the answer in case anyone else runs into this.  I also updated my project from net48 target to net8.0-windows (.NET Core).  It looks like the CefSharp.Common package is not the right one and there is a separate CefSharp.Common.NETCore package that has to be installed for .NET Core projects.  Once I installed THAT one the errors went away and it worked.  Weird though that when I used intellisense it lead me to the package that was not core.  I had to search for the common package on NuGet and noticed that the core one existed.
Hopefully it helps someone else.
